# How can I relate inner product $\left<x|A|x\right>$ to the matrix norm $||A||$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$|||A||| = \max \frac{\left<x|A^{\dagger}A|x\right>^{\frac{1}{2}}}{||x||}$

But how can I relate $$\left<x|A|x\right>$$ only to $|||A|||$ or some other matrix norm?

Comment: There isn't a general relation between the two. The matrix norm does bound the expression you have, however.

Comment: @paul why it is bounded by the norm? Could you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

It's Cauchy Schwarz:
$$
|\langle x|A|x\rangle|\leq \|x\|\,\|Ax\|.
$$
And
$$
\|Ax\|^2=\langle x|A^\dagger A|x\rangle\leq \|A\|^2\,\|x\|^2.
$$
So
$$
|\langle x|A|x\rangle|\leq\|A\|\,\|x\|^2.
$$

Comment: But A need not be self adjoint. Does it hold of A is not self adjoint?

Comment: I'm not requiring $A$ to be selfadjoint at any step.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I'm using the OP's definition.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I was misreading it the whole time!  Sorry.

Comment: No worries, I do it more often than you do.

Comment: But since whether or not A is self -adjoint or not $|\langle x|A|x\rangle|\leq\|A\|\,\|x\|^2$. Does A being self-adjoint result in a tighter bound as there is no need for Cauchy Schwarz if A is self-adjoint?

Comment: @peter: you need CS, whether $A$ is selfadjoint or not. It doesn't make a difference. And, for any $A$, whether selfadjoint or not, you can always find $x$ such that the two sides of the inequality are arbitrarily close, so the inequality is as sharp as it can be.